# O_FLAGS to append or create file. With open() in C unix

Tags: c, linux, file, unix

So I have the following code. The str_arr[] just contain combination of console commands ex ls, sort.. and filenames. And execute() forks a child process.

```
for(int y=0; y<i-1; y++){
    if(type_arr[y]==0){

    }
    else if(type_arr[y]==1){

    }
    else if(type_arr[y]==2){
        int fw1=open(str_arr[y+1], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT |S_IRWXU);
        int sv_out1=dup(1);
        dup2(fw1, 1);
        close(fw1);
        execute(str_arr[y]);
        dup2(sv_out1, 1);
    }
    else if(type_arr[y]==3){
        int fw=open(str_arr[y+1], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
        int sv_out=dup(1);
        dup2(fw, 1);
        close(fw);
        execute(str_arr[y]);
        dup2(sv_out, 1);
    }
}
```

when **type_arr[y]==3**, The code should create or overwrite file, if file exist. This works. However when **type_arr[y]==2** the code should create or append file, this does not work, in fact it only prints normally to console if file exist (using ls), if file does exist it does create a new file. Whats wrong here ? these O_FLAGS should append or create file right?

Comment: What is that `S_IRWXU` doing in your open mode? And where are your error checks?

Comment: S_IRWXU does this: 00700 user (file owner) has read, write, and execute permission

Comment: Yes. Those are permission bits. Why are you passing them as part of your open mode?

Comment: because if has to create as well, when I did not put it created files in read only mode.

Comment: You're not making sense. And now that you've added `O_CREAT` to the open mode, you also need a 3rd argument (the file permissions for new files).

Comment: yeah since I been playing around with flags I posted the wrong at first.  O_WRONLY is to write, O_APPEND is to append,  O_CREAT is to create if does not exist, and  S_IRWXU is for permissions. How does the third argument works?

Comment: Permissions don't belong in the second argument. They belong in the third. Second paragraph of the BSD version of the man page.

Comment: "how does the third argument work". It's all described in the [open man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open)

Comment: hmmm ty i have figured out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append or create a file use:

```
int fw1=open(str_arr[y+1], O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, FILE_PERMISSIONS);
```

and use the third argument for the file permissions (ex: `FILE_PERMISSIONS = 0777`)